# Why are my Flutter (dart) icons turn into weird icons?

Tags: android, flutter, dart, mobile, icons

Basically, I have this nice amazing app, and for no actual reason, the icons turned into weird icons like the one in the image.

[image: SS]

I searched the web, but nothing helped, I tried changing the color of the icon and stuff like that and nothing helped.

Comment: Do you have `use-material-design: true` in your `pubspec.yaml` file?

Comment: Update question with code, MRE.

Comment: Update code snippet of the icon or screen, it helps to detect the issue.

Answer (score 1):

Ok turns out i was doing some stuff in my pubspec yaml file, and turns out I had accidently turned user-material-design off, so if any one has this problem:

Go to the `pubspec.yaml` file and then you will find `use-material-design: true`
MAKE SURE IT'S TRUE